# how to install Phalcon on XAMP

Tags: php, installation, xampp, phalcon

I am following **document** instruction to install Phalcon on XAMP , from **[here](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/webserver-xampp)**

It is said to download **x86 version** for **windows** in **document**

but when I go to **Download page** there is **not** that version there **[here](https://phalcon.io/en-us/download/linux).**

**only** **x64** is **available** there and when I install  `phalcon-php8.0-nts-windows2019-vs16-x64.zip`

and run **XAMP** , I see it is **not** installed because in `phpinfo()` it doesn't displayed .

[image]

so what should I do ?

Comment: ignore the comment continue with x64, your PHP is x64

Comment: i did it and installed this phalcon-php8.0-nts-windows2019-vs16-x64.zip 
but i think it is not installed because there is not phalcon in phpinfo();

Comment: is windows variable also needed to be set?

Comment: What does your PHP.INI look like?  Where did you install the php_phalcon.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Install PSR.dll from https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/psr/1.2.0/  and add it to your php.ini before Phalcon. According to your PhpInfo you will need to download php_psr-1.2.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64.zip